# mssql stored procedure separator of commands

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to run about 60000 commands where I execute a stored procedure with different parameters. I generated these commands, but I am not able to run them all together, because of error "Incorect syntax near 'cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp'"

I have got following commands:

```
cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '18604','ResourceSelf',5025008;
cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '62454','ResourceSelf',5025009;
cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '14428','ResourceSelf',5025010;
```

I tried to execute them with ; and also without ; at the end of the command, but it's not working. What "separator" should I use?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Have you tried to `EXEC` them?

Comment: What are the parameters for this stored procedure?

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen: do you meen like: exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '18604','ResourceSelf',5025008;
exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '62454','ResourceSelf',5025009;
exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '14428','ResourceSelf',5025010;?

Comment: Parameters are: [USER], '14428','ResourceSelf',5025010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec is the command, e.g.

`exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '18604','ResourceSelf',5025008`

`exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '62454','ResourceSelf',5025009`

`exec cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '14428','ResourceSelf',5025010`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with a `GO`

```
EXEC cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '18604','ResourceSelf',5025008;
GO
EXEC cmn_sec_assign_inst_right_sp [USER], '62454','ResourceSelf',5025009;
....
```

The GO will instruct that it's the end of the *batch*.

If this doesn't work, can you show the first part of the SP, where you have defined the `params`?